# Account Advanced Find View has Duplicate Filter

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

If I create a new Account Advanced find view I am finding some very odd behaviour.

I follow these steps:

- Create new view for Account
- Go to Criteria
- Criteria has been prepopulated as below

[image]

Which is odd on its own - why prepopulate?

Anyway, if I then add something, say  `Status = Active` , it duplicates the first criteria as below:

[image]

Other than 'your server is FUBAR'd' - anyone have any ideas what could be causing it?

edit: if I export, the XML does not show the duplicated filters as below shows:

[image]

Comment: What if you add another criteria? Does it repeat the first line for a third time?

Comment: I can only offer you moral support on this one, along with cudos on *FUBAR* - didn't know anybody else was using it. Does that happen for any field? What if you remove one of the filter? If you set them to different values etc.?

Comment: @mjhouseman haha I just tried it. Yes it was added a third time - but it was filter1 AND (filter2 AND filter3). Eugh.

Comment: It has been raised with MS - I will update if/when we get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply received from Microsoft. A colleague has verified this and found it fixed the issue in our case.

A filter had been applied to the default view for `Account` (I must admit I wasn't aware of this!).

When you click to create a new view, part of the code executed retrieves the current default view and uses that as a template.

**Removing all filters on the default view therefore solve this issue.**

I'm not quite sure why it should have had the affect it did when adding new criteria, but I think I'll choose not to think about that!